# Unable to update symfony/translations from composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, lumen

I am having trouble updating my Lumen project with composer, as it fails updating symfony/translations. When I `composer update` on my local it updates just fine. When I then try to update on my LAMP server, I get an error that it is not a git repository. It then asks to reinstall. I choose `yes` and it removes the old, but cannot install the new.

```
$ composer update 
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/translation (v3.1.8 => v3.1.10)    Update failed (Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
)
Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing symfony/translation (v3.1.8)


  [RuntimeException]                                                    
  Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d                              
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git  


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I have tried `--prefer-dist` and the same result.

This is a Lumen 5.3 project, so the dependency is from Lumen.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleared my vendor directory `rm -rf vendor/*` and reinstalled everything `composer install` and everything installed and works correctly.

`- Installing symfony/translation (v3.1.10) Downloading: 100%`

That was a solution, but if anyone can explain what might have happened and why it could not update?